# georeferencing a trajectory from inertial sensors (IMU)

Tags: gps, openstreetmap, accelerometer, imu, sensor-fusion

There are data from tracking a moving object based on inertial measurement unit (IMU), using sensors like accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer. From these data (by sensor fusion) is generated a trajectory (polyline) and rendered into maps.

Question is how this trajectory to georeference into map (e.g. openstreetmap) with **minimum GPS intervention** and with good accuracy (i tried GPS+IMU sensor fusion solution, but gps values was very unstable in dense urban areas..). Understandably starting coordinates must be selected.. Is there some kind of preferred georeferencing technique ? thanks.